# cout statement causes perceptron accuracy to change

Tags: c++

I implemented a perceptron in C++ that distinguishes between a 2 and a 6 from the MNIST dataset. However, I discovered some odd behavior when I comment out a cout statement in the testing loop. When I have the testing loop print out the predicted digit and the actual digit, the final accuracy of the perceptron is much higher than when I don't have the loop print it.

I'm running this code in vscode by the way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include "../MNISTReader/mnistreader.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

const double ALPHA = 0.02; // Learning rate
int trainingPasses = 100; // Number of training passes
int testNums[2] = {2, 6}; // Numbers to classify
bool writeToFile = false; // Whether or not to write training weights to a csv file

// Read MNIST dataset
mnistreader mnist(
    "../MNISTDataset/trainImages",
    "../MNISTDataset/trainLabels",
    "../MNISTDataset/testImages",
    "../MNISTDataset/testLabels",
    2000, // Number of training data to use
    100, // Number of testing data to use
    true
);

// Define weights and bias
double* w = (double*) malloc(mnist.imgSize * sizeof(double));
double b;

// Function used to compute the dot product of the weight matrix and the pixel data
double forwardPass(double *x) {
    double sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < mnist.imgSize; ++i) {
        sum += w[i] * x[i];
    }
    sum += b;
    return sum;
}

// Function used to train the perceptron
void train() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mnist.trainSize; ++i) {
        double pred = forwardPass(mnist.trainImgData[i]) * mnist.trainLblData[i];
        if (pred <= 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mnist.imgSize; ++j) {
                w[j] += ALPHA * mnist.trainLblData[i] * mnist.trainImgData[i][j];
            }
            b += ALPHA * mnist.trainLblData[i];
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    // Initialize weights and bias
    srand(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < mnist.imgSize; ++i) {
        w[i] = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }
    b = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;

    // Preprocess data
    mnist.selectData(testNums, 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < mnist.trainSize; ++i) {
        if (mnist.trainLblData[i] == testNums[0]) {
            mnist.trainLblData[i] = -1;
        }
        else {
            mnist.trainLblData[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    // Train model
    steady_clock::time_point t0 = steady_clock::now();
    if (writeToFile) {
        ofstream wData;
        wData.open("wData.csv");
        for (int i = 0; i < trainingPasses; ++i) {
            train();
            for (int j = 0; j < mnist.imgSize; ++j) {
                wData << w[j] << ",";
            }
            wData << b << endl;
        }
        wData.close();
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < trainingPasses; ++i) {
            train();
        }
    }
    steady_clock::time_point t1 = steady_clock::now();
    cout << "Training took " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count() << " ms" << endl;

    // Test model
    int truePos = 0;
    int trueNeg = 0;
    int falsePos = 0;
    int falseNeg = 0;
    double accuracy = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        double pred = forwardPass(mnist.testImgData[i], i, true);
        int actual = mnist.testLblData[i];

        cout << "[" << i << "] pred: " << (pred < 0 ? testNums[0] : testNums[1])
        << " | actual: " << actual << endl; // This print statement changes the accuracy

        if (actual == testNums[0]) {
            if (pred < 0) {
                trueNeg++;
            }
            else {
                falsePos++;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (pred < 0) {
                falseNeg++;
            }
            else {
                truePos++;
            }
        }
    }
    accuracy = 100.0 * (truePos + trueNeg) / mnist.testSize;
    cout << truePos + trueNeg << "/" << mnist.testSize << " correct" << endl;
    cout << "The model is " << accuracy << "%" << " accurate" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The mnist object is from a class that I created which read the mnist dataset and stores the labels in a 1-D array of integers and the images in a 2-D array where each element is an array with 784 (28x28) doubles. The arrays are aligned so the label in trainLblData[n] is the digit at trainImgData[n].

This is the output when the cout statement is present in the testing loop

```
Training took 114 ms
[0] pred: 2 | actual: 2
[1] pred: 2 | actual: 6
[2] pred: 6 | actual: 6
[3] pred: 6 | actual: 6
[4] pred: 2 | actual: 2
[5] pred: 2 | actual: 2
[6] pred: 2 | actual: 2
[7] pred: 2 | actual: 2
[8] pred: 6 | actual: 6
[9] pred: 2 | actual: 6
[10] pred: 2 | actual: 6
[11] pred: 2 | actual: 2
[12] pred: 2 | actual: 2
[13] pred: 6 | actual: 6
[14] pred: 2 | actual: 2
[15] pred: 6 | actual: 6
[16] pred: 6 | actual: 6
[17] pred: 6 | actual: 6
15/18 correct
The model is 83.3333% accurate
```

This is the output when the cout statement is commented out

```
Training took 162 ms
10/18 correct
The model is 55.5556% accurate
```

Not quite sure what could be causing this change in accuracy. I've even put in a breakpoint and viewed the "pred" variable and it also changes when the cout statement is present. I'm not sure if there's some memory issues or something's up with the compiler but it's consistent between runs of the code.

Comment: It looks like you have _undefined behavior_. If you are using `g++` or `clang++`, compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and run the program again. It may provide some info.

Comment: Someone has downvoted which is often due to using C arrays when https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray is in C++ which includes `*` and `sum`.

Comment: @QuentinUK it would probably be more accurate to point out that with the exception of the output, I don’t see much if any c++ code. Even the casts are straight c style casts.

Comment: At the very least you have ub on `sum` you use it without initialization.

Comment: Re: "When I ... print out the predicted digit ... the final accuracy ... is much higher" -- that's because it knows it's being watched, so it's more careful.

Comment: @Taekahn turns out you were right. I forgot to initialize sum and doing so actually fixed that undefined behavior. Not sure how I missed that but thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to @Taekhan. I forgot to initialize “sum” in my forwardPass function which was causing undefined behavior in my code. Initializing it actually fixed the problem.